# Accents in a webpage are not working

Tags: html, css, diacritics

**Hello**

I have a problem with a website I'm building. The thing is that it's in spanish, and it uses some accents in the vowels. The problem is that the accents aren't showing correctly. I'mm upload a pic to show the problem. I'm using the font Myriad Pro but I've already tried with some others that don't give a problem at all in normal text editing, like Helvetica.

This is the image showing the problem and the code related to it.

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Specify in your `head` that you are using `iso-8859-1` encoding: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the actual *file encoding* (or *charset*) in the HEAD of your HTML code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    ...
</head>
```

In this example, UTF-8 encoding is assumed.

Comment: Thanks to both! I completely forgot to add the charset. :) Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

To display an HTML page in a proper way, the browser must know what character set (character encoding) to use.

W3C have a lot of info!

The answer was already given here, but for further reading check this out http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/

I think it will help you